Can you log websockets request sent from a server to a client?
I am working on creating a Chrome extension that injects JavaScript code into my website to log the WebSocket requests that the user receives when they run the extension.
Let's say I am connected to a WebSocket server on my website at wss://server.example.com, and it sends data to my client like {"message": "example"}.
I don't want to create a new connection to log; instead, I want to log the connection that is automatically established when I connect to the site.
So, doing something like const ws = new WebSocket('wss://server.example.com'); and logging the requests it sends is not what I am trying to achieve. I want to log the requests from the connection that is automatically established when you connect to sites with a WebSocket server.
If I find a piece of code that works, shouldn't I be able to put it in the console to check if it works?
I have tried using different scripts with const OriginalWebSocket = window.WebSocket; to create a copy of the WebSocket connections and log them myself in a script. However, it often returns undefined. Does anyone have any idea how I can log the requests?

Have you found where the existing websocket connection is held? If it's accessible then you can simply add a new event handler to it. Some more context around the current code structure would help

This will intercept and log all WebSocket connections and messages made by the page.
const OriginalWebSocket = window.WebSocket;

window.WebSocket = function(url, protocols) {
  const ws = new OriginalWebSocket(url, protocols);

  ws.addEventListener('open', (event) => {
    console.log('WebSocket connection opened:', url);
  });

  ws.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    console.log('Received WebSocket message:', event.data);
  });

  ws.addEventListener('close', (event) => {
    console.log('WebSocket connection closed');
  });

  ws.addEventListener('error', (event) => {
    console.error('WebSocket error:', event);
  });

  return ws;
};


When i try to run it in the console of a website it doesn't intercept the websockets it just returns undefined and then goes to a new line. If i inject it using a Chrome extension will it work then?

Yes, injecting the code via a Chrome extension should work. If you're running the code directly in the browser console and getting undefined, I suggests that the WebSocket constructor was already used or initialized by the time you ran the script, or perhaps the timing of the script execution doesn't match the timing when the page creates WebSocket instances.
